# Vue.js webpack error importing css file from external library

Tags: webpack, vue.js, css-loader

I am trying to import aos ( animation library) into my test app

I installed it normally   yarn add aos
and  in my vue , I am using the following code

```
<script>
....
import AOS from 'aos/dist/aos.js'
import 'aos/dist/aos.css'

methods: {
...
installAos: function () {
  const aos = new AOS({ duration: 1200 })
  aos.init()
}, 
mounted: function () {
this.$nextTick(function () {
  ....
  this.installAos()
})
}
```

I get an error upon building w webpack (3.6.0 )

WARNING  Compiled with 1 warnings                                                             14:36:15

```
 warning  in ./node_modules/aos/dist/aos.css

 (Emitted value instead of an instance of Error)   resolve-url-loader cannot operate: CSS error
  ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/yves/Developments  /WIP/VUE.JS/hello-vue/node_modules/a
os/dist/aos.css.map'
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:646:18)
```

seems to be related to the the loading of external css files ..
there is no aos.css.map

Answer (score 0):

foundwhy ...

a commented line at the end of the aos.css package :

```
/*# sourceMappingURL=aos.css.map*/
```

if I suppress this line , then it's building correctly

I don't understand why this line is checked by the resolve-url-loader plugin... I'll write it as an issue to the resolve-url-loader support team...